# What causes this error? "CALayer position contains NaN: [240 nan]"

Tags: iphone, core-animation, calayer

I've seen this happen whenever i rotate a screen that has a `UITableView` on it.  I've found out that it happens inbetween the `willRotate` and `didRotate` method calls in `UIViewController` My co-workers have seen it in other spots as well, usually around rotation.  It hadnt started happening until very recently, and we're stumped as to how we should deal with it (google searches don't turn up the error message in its exact form).  Has anyone else encountered this that knows what to do about it?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I've found the problem.

When you reset the frame of a `tableview`, it calls the delegate method `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` for each row in the table so it can recalculate its content size if it needs to.  At that point, we do some special handling to return the height, and due to some bad assumptions in our code, we mistakenly returned `NaN` due to a divide by zero error (the variable we divide by was assumed to never be zero).  Making sure that we do not divide by zero here fixed it.

Comment: I'm getting the same error (both position & bounds contain NaN, msgs usually come in pairs.)  Only right before my view displays.  No rotation, no tables, no fancy calculation.  A simple dark-grey view with a label, "Processing..." and a progressIndicator.

Anyone else got ideas on this one?

Comment: put some breakpoints in your viewdidload/viewwillappear methods and make sure you're not dividing by zero anywhere accidentally.

Comment: It may or may not be relevant but I had seen this crash much more consistently in Mavericks OSX 10.9, however was not seen again after the OSX 10.9.2 update.

Comment: This gave me a better picture of the issue on my project... Since I'm using separate storyboards, the viewController that I'm presenting has a tableView that I'm not sending the correct values to.

Answer (score 41):

(Decided to take this out of comments and put it as an answer, since I think it's a darned good answer :)

Ha! I had an NaN calculation (div0), too. Key debugging aid: the message in question is output by NSLog(), so set a breakpoint on NSLog() and watch what the OS is doing at that time. For me, it was myUISlider.value = NaN.

To set breakpoint:

**XCode 3.x**

- CMD-SHIFT-Y (debug window.)
- Breakpoints button.
- "Double-click for symbol"
- Type in "NSLog" (no quotes.)

**XCode 4.x**

- CMD-6 (breakpoints navigator.)
- "+" to add breakpoint (lower left.)
- Select ADD SYMBOLIC BREAKPOINT.
- Symbol: NSLog
- Confirm: Done.

**XCode 5.x - 7.1 (at least)**
(Same as 4.x, except breakpoints navigator is CMD-7, now.)

Run app, watch it break on NSLog, check the stack traces.

Comment: This is the answered that actually matters when it comes to this exception. It's important to notice that this exception can be raised from components that use the CALayer and we API users don't know of their existence (thanks to encapsulation).

Comment: Morkrom, you're thinking iOS version.  I'm talking about XCode version.  I haven't had a chance to check out XCode 5.x, yet, but I bet it's not too hard to figure out.

Comment: Great, +1 for debugging approach.

Comment: I did this, but nothing happens. I still have no idea where the crash came from. Did something changed on Xcode 7? Btw, its Swift.

Comment: @Caio: If you didn't get the breakpoint, (a) verify that your breakpoint breaks on NSLog() (do a test-log), (b) Perhaps the error you're getting is not output by NSLog(); see if you can break elsewhere.  The key bit about my answer is: since I couldn't find the code to break on, I broke on the bit that output the message.  Maybe look in your stack trace for some iOS exception handling code and try breaking on that.

Comment: @Olie Finally find out what the hell was happening. The division by zero was made by internal UIScrollView methods, so that's why breakpoint was not breaking on NSLog. Sometimes one constraint can be 0.

Comment: Debugging part is useless for crashes coming from 3rd party SKDs

Comment: In Xcode 8, I had a `CALayer position contains NaN` terminating as an `NSException`. Setting an Exception Breakpoint: All Exceptions gave me the stack trace. (Symbolic Breakpoint: `NSLog` did not.)

Answer (score 16):

I've spent a day trying to find the code that causes same problem and solved it within a minutes after enabling "break on exception" in Xcode. Check [this tutorial](http://blog.manbolo.com/2012/01/23/xcode-tips-1-break-on-exceptions) to see how to enable it.

Comment: Can you include a short summary of the page's content? This is so that future readers of this post can get the information they're looking for quickly and easily.

Comment: @gobernador I will as it's just helped me out!

To find the exact line where your app died, go to the breakpoint tab on the left of xcode, click +, add a new `Exception Breakpoint` and leave the settings as default. Click Done and re-run your app.

Answer (score 13):

I had this problem when i was assumed that:

`tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:` returned an `NSInteger`, but it returns `CGFloat`...

changing:

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

to

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

fixed my issue.

Edit:

At some point I figured out how computers work below the C level, so I thought I would share it... (I will use an register names from x86_64 as I am most familiar with them, ARM would be slightly different but analogous)

```
int f(){
          float someFloat=5.0f;
          return someFloat;
       }
```

results in converting the value of `someFloat` to an integer type then copying that to a particular register: `%rax` then calling the return instruction.

```
float f(){
          float someFloat=5.0f;
          return someFloat;
       }
```

results in copying the value of `someFloat` from its current location to a particular register: `%xmm0` then calling the return instruction.

So if you have the wrong prototype the calling code will expect the value to be in the wrong place, you will end up really returning a garbage value.

Answer (score 3):

This error also cost me a long time.
At the end I found my colleague wrote something like this:

```
UIEdgeInsets a;
a.left = (...some calculation);
button.imageEdgeInsets = a;
```

And I rewrote these code like this and fix the issue:

```
UIEdgeInsets a;
a.left = (...some calculation);
a.top = 0;
a.bottom = 0;
a.right = 0;
button.imageEdgeInsets = a;
```

some value of UIEdgeInsets isn't initialised properly, and it sometimes turn into a NaN value, and crash the application.
More generally, you should check whether all values of C-style structs are initialised properly.

Answer (score 2):

There is an another way to reproduce the issue: using `insetBy(dx:dy:)` on a too small rect

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can try this `yourTableview?.bounces = false`. It works for me.