# Application get crashed due to "SIGABRT" in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, crash

I am developing iPad Application and did all orientations. But some times the application get crashed due to "SIGABRT" and this is my error log is,

```
  *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'CALayerInvalidGeometry', reason: 'CALayer position contains NaN: [15 nan]'
```

I have used three table view in the apps, so i have added the labels and images are into the table view cell.And i have displayed all the contents are dynamically and set the frame size is also dynamically.  Please help me out

Thanks

Comment: Try here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025176/what-causes-this-error-calayer-position-contains-nan-240-nan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probable getting somewhere a division by zero operation, if your contents are dynamically set. Try to debug your code.