# CALayer position contains NaN: [nan 15]

Tags: ios, iphone, calayer

My iphone app crashes showing error

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'CALayerInvalidGeometry', reason: 'CALayer position contains NaN: [nan 15]'
```

What does this mean ?

Comment: This link will be helpful : [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025176/what-causes-this-error-calayer-position-contains-nan-240-nan][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025176/what-causes-this-error-calayer-position-contains-nan-240-nan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"CALayer position contains NaN: [nan 15]" indicates that you have a division by zero somewhere.  NSLog() will help you isolate it.  If you posted the stack log, more help would have been available.